# How to save UITableView data to DB?

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, uitableview, xamarin

I started to use Xamarin.iOS, and the first app i'm trying to build is a Notes App, just like default Apple Notes app.

I'm using the recipe from Xamarin Recipes, and used `UITableView` to show the data, and `TableSource` class to manage cells and items.

The problem start when I want to save the data, so I will be able to load the notes after reopen the app. I'm using ADO.Net, and its working well. I tried to save the data to table contains to columns: ID & Text.

The issue is how to work with the DB table and at the same time with the `UITableView`.

**For example:** I loaded few items, let say that they will get the ID from Db: 1, 2, 3, same as they are in `UITableView` `IndexPath`. Now i'm deleting item number 2, so than item that was num 3, is now 2 in `UITableView`.

When trying to access and edit item number 2 (old 3) - Can't find him in the DB.

The reason for the problem is known, but how to fix it - I really dont know.

Any suggestion will be great.

Thanks, Tal.

Answer (score 0):

you are doing little wrong lets start say you have your record id is unique may be 1 - 2 - 3

you now forget about indexPath just focus on your record id,

load the data and now you have deleted the record 2, no problem edited your data id 3 and updated into DB, but for this you have to use array of dictionary so that eavery record have there property like

id and message so you always update the Right dataset